# Capitalize first letter of each word of input

Tags: code-golf, string

This is a relatively quick one, but I'm sure you'll like it.

Codegolf a program that will take input in the form of a sentence and then provide the output with the first letter capitalized in each word.

Rules:

1. Submissions may not be in the form of a function. So no:

   `function x(y){z=some_kind_of_magic(y);return z;}` as your final answer... Your code must show that it takes input, and provides output.
2. The code must preserve any other capital letters the input has. So

   ```
   eCommerce and eBusiness are cool, don't you agree, Richard III?
   ```

   will be rendered as

   ```
   ECommerce And EBusiness Are Cool, Don't You Agree, Richard III?
   ```
3. Some of you may be thinking, "Easy, I'll just use regex!" and so using the native regex in your chosen golfing language will incur a 30 character penalty which will be applied to your final code count. *Evil laugh*
4. A "word" in this case is anything separated by a space. Therefore `palate cleanser` is two words, whereas `pigeon-toed` is considered one word. `if_you_love_her_then_you_should_put_a_ring_on_it` is considered one word. If a word starts with a non-alphabetical character, the word is preserved, so `_this` after rendering remains as `_this`. (Kudos to Martin Buttner for pointing this test case out).

   - 4b. There is no guarantee that words in the input phrase will be separated by a single space.
5. Test Case, (please use to test your code):

   Input:

   ```
   eCommerce rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   ECommerce Rocks. CrazyCamelCase Stuff. _those  Pigeon-toed Shennanigans. Fiery Trailblazing 345 Thirty-two Roger. The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs. Clancy Brown Would Have Been Cool As Lex Luthor. Good_bye
   ```
6. This is code golf, shortest code wins...

Good luck...

Comment: Oh crap, I was thinking of multiple spaces but forgot to mention it... I've updated the brief accordingly... The brief will be locked from this point forward.

Comment: What about spaces at the end of the line? Do we have to preserve them? Can we add one if it serves our needs?

Comment: Dennis, please preserve spaces from the input...

Comment: != TitleCase dam it! c# loses AGAIN!

Comment: @WallyWest I don't think there should be a ` at the end of the example output? Also a double space `before Pigeon-toed`?

Comment: @Tim The double space before Pigeon-toed is **correct**. He said to preserve spacing.

Comment: What separates the words?  Any whitespace (tabs, newlines, etc) or just spaces?

Comment: Is this ASCII only or should the answer handle unicode?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski just standard space (ASCII 32)

Comment: @Bakuriu At this point it's just standard ASCII...

Comment: Does ”Ascii only” mean that answers that correctly capitalize e.g. ä to Ä are incorrent? Such as this one: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49950/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-of-input#answer-49956

Comment: @leo: Reading the OP's comment in context, it says the code doesn't have to handle non-ASCII characters. I'd say that means behavior for non-ASCII letters is undefined.

Comment: Not even an honorable mention for [the 13-byte Perl solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50028/31388)?

Comment: Honorable mention made! Nice work!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## CJam, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
Lq{_eu?_S-}/;
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Lq%7B_eu%3F_S-%7D%2F%3B&input=eCommerce%20rocks.%20crazyCamelCase%20stuff.%20_those%20%20pigeon-toed%20shennanigans.%20Fiery%20trailblazing%20345%20thirty-two%20Roger.%20The%20quick%20brown%20fox%20jumped%20over%20the%20lazy%20dogs.%20Clancy%20Brown%20would%20have%20been%20cool%20as%20Lex%20Luthor.%20good_bye).

#### Pseudocode

```
L             e# B := ""
 q            e# Q := input()
  {       }/  e# for C in Q:
   _eu?       e#     C := B ? C : uppercase(C)
       _S-    e#     B := string(C).strip(" ")
            ; e# discard(B)
```

All modified characters C are left on the stack and, therefore, printed when exiting.

Comment: Damn this is clever. D:

Comment: I have to agree, outgolfing someone by 4 chars in a codegolf language is a feat in itself... well done.

Comment: @WallyWest: Golfing languages can give the impression that they kinda golf themselves, but I assure you that they don't. TMTOWTDI is true for *all* languages and especially for those with a lot of built-ins. Sometimes you [win](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49671), sometimes you [lose](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38694) and sometimes you feel like you've been [hit by a truck](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37905).

Answer (score 13):

## CSS 2.1, 49

```css
:after{content:attr(t);text-transform:capitalize}
```

**Explanation**:

- The [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function takes the input from a `t` (text) HTML attribute.
- The input is capitalized by setting [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) to `capitalize`.
- The output is provided as a generated content, using the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property on an [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

**Runnable snippet**:

```css
:after {
    content: attr(t);
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div t="eCommerce rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye"></div>
```

**Note**: [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#text-transform) specified the desired behavior: `capitalize` uppercased the first character of each word. However, [CSS3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#text-transform) uppercases first [typographic letter unit](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#typographic-letter-unit) of each word. So the snippet above won't work properly neither on old IE, which didn't follow CSS 2.1; nor on new compliant browsers which follow CSS3.

Comment: Oh, this is clever!

Comment: (too bad about the `_those` problem on CSS3 browsers, but I'm still upvoting because of the unique way of solving the problem.)

Comment: @Oriol, "oh this is clever!" indeed! Sorry IQAndreas, I have to borrow your comment here... this is an ingenious approach to solving the problem... i will have to make use of this approach...

Answer (score 11):

## Perl, 13 bytes

```
perl -040pe '$_="\u$_"'
```

9 bytes plus 4 bytes for `040p` (assuming I've interpreted the [rules on special invocations](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/31388) correctly).

`-040` sets the input record separator `$/` to a single space, so spaces are preserved; the `\u` escape sequence converts the next character to title case.

Comment: Great work, honorable mention for using the command line!

Answer (score 10):

## Javascript (*ES6*), 77 bytes

```js
alert(prompt().split(' ').map(x=>x&&x[0].toUpperCase()+x.slice(1)).join(' '))
```

#### Commented

```js
alert( // output
    prompt(). // take input
    split(' '). // split by spaces
    map(x=> // map function to array
        x && // if x, empty string "" is falsey and returns itself
        x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1) // capaitalize 1st char and concatenate the rest
    ).
    join(' ') // join array with spaces
)
```

Comment: What happens if words are separated by multiple spaces? [4b]

Comment: @Caek It's handled by the `x&&`. An empty string is falsey so the `&&` short-circuits and returns the left operand, the empty string. Spaces are preserved.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. Might help me figure out how I can get it to work now.

Comment: This will capitalize even non Ascii characters, so that å will become Å!

Comment: -4 bytes by calling `split\` \`` and `join\` \`` as [Tagged Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

Answer (score 8):

## Perl Version < 5.18, <strike>30</strike> <strike>27</strike> <strike>26</strike> 25

```
say map"\u$_",split$,=$"
```

`24` characters `+1` for `-n`.

`\u` makes the next character in a string [uppercase](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). @ThisSuitIsBlackNot pointed this out to save 1 byte. Before we were using the function `ucfirst`.

From the [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html),

> As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the
>   command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a literal
>   string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20" ,
>   but not e.g. / / ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is
>   removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as
>   if it were /\s+/ ; in particular, this means that any contiguous
>   whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.
>   However, this special treatment can be avoided by specifying the
>   pattern / / instead of the string " " , thereby allowing only a single
>   space character to be a separator. In earlier Perls this special case
>   was restricted to the use of a plain " " as the pattern argument to
>   split, in Perl 5.18.0 and later this special case is triggered by any
>   expression which evaluates as the simple string " " .

Since `$"` evaluates to a space, this will preserve the spaces. Since we want to both set `$,` to a space character, and input a space character to the split, @nutki pointed out we can do both as the input to the split. That saves 3 bytes from what we had before, which was first setting `$,` and then inputting `$"` to the split.

Using a `,` for map instead of `{}` saves an additional byte, as @alexander-brett pointed out.

Run with:

```
echo 'eCommerce     rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye' | perl -nE'say map"\u$_",split$,=$"'
```

Comment: Save 1 byte with `...map"\u$_",split...`

Comment: @alexander-brett thanks! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
lS/{S+(eu\+}/W<
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=lS%2F%7BS%2B(eu%5C%2B%7D%2FW%3C&input=_this%20%20eCommerce%20rocks.%20crazyCamelCase%20stuff.%20_those%20pigeon-toed%20shennanigans.%20Fiery%20trailblazing%20345%20thirty-two%20Roger.%20The%20quick%20brown%20fox%20jumped%20over%20the%20lazy%20dogs.%20Clancy%20Brown%20would%20have%20been%20cool%20as%20Lex%20Luthor.%20good_bye)

Fairly straightforward implementation of the spec. Make use of the new `{}&` to avoid errors for consecutive spaces.

*Two bytes saved by Dennis.*

Comment: Great stuff! Is CJam primarily just a golfing language or does it have some practical commercial applications?

Comment: @WallyWest No it's just a golfing language. It definitely doesn't have *commercial* applications, but I personally use it occasionally for quick throw-away scripts (because it has a lot of built-ins, and if you know what you're doing, then typing fewer characters is quicker than typing more characters ;)).

Comment: You can save a few bytes by appending a space to each word. Depending  on the OP's answer to my question, this could get you to either 14 or 12 bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Oh right, I was playing around with that, but didn't consider simply adding it before pulling off the first character. I'll change that tomorrow, thank you!

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I changed it, but I'm not sure what 14-byte version you meant. If you're talking about omitting the second `+`, then that breaks if the input contains trailing spaces.

Comment: Yes, I miscounted the spaces. :(

Answer (score 7):

### C, <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```
a;main(c){while(~(c=getchar()))putchar(a?c:toupper(c)),a=c-32;}
```

*Fix: some compilers (such as Clang) don't like an int parameters in place of argv, so I moved it to a global variable. The byte count stays the same. Thanks to squeamish ossifrage for noticing.*
*Down to 63 bytes, thanks Dennis.*

Ungolfed:

```
int a;

int main(int c) {
    while(~(c = getchar()))
        putchar(a ? c : toupper(c)),
        a = c - ' ';
}
```

Pretty straightforward: if a is false, the character is converted to uppercase. It is set after reading a space: c - ' ' is false only if c == ' '. toupper() ignores everything that is not a lowercase letter, so symbols and multiple spaces are fine. -1 has all bits set, so when getchar() returns -1 the NOT operator makes it zero, and the loop stops.
a is declared as a global variable, so it is initializd to zero (false). This ensures that the first word is capitalized.

Comment: `while(~(c=getchar())` — I like that. Clang won't actually compile this, but you can get the same character count with `c;main(a){...}`

Comment: If you swap the declarations of `a` and `c` and the order of the ternary operator, you can replace `==` with `-` to save one byte.

Comment: You are right, of course.

Comment: Nice! +1 The program would work the same when using `while(!(c = getchar()))`, right?

Comment: @Cool Guy: Nope, the bitwise `~` and the logical `!` are not the same. In C anything that is not zero is considered true, so your condition would be like `while((c = getchar()) == 0)` which of course won't work. The bitwise NOT operator `~` negates the value bit-by-bit. To break the loop, `~c` must be zero: this means that all bits have to be one, so that when negated they become all zeroes. That value (for a 32bit int) is `0xFFFFFFFF`, which, if signed, is `-1` (EOF).

Comment: putchar(c>96?c&&95:c) //lowercase letters are 64 more than upper case letters, and begin at 97. this will do funny things to words begining with chars above 'z'

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY7BTsMwEER/ZY/JIT1QuBBVSETqqSfEvdpsNrap4w0bu6mL4NeDBccZzXsaagzRtmE7oQsV1V@jaNX@VHQwHMmiVnXd4oGa/UM9p/8GX@g5Sppn1kLU7fe2cSfTxEoMKnRZdkCK99zhxL7DhWGJaRx3cI5WSoLZGZbQROEBFsshYHAGQ@GOjjVDVHS@93h3wcD@8QmidRpzE1eBNzGsO3i3DJ/J0QV6lTXAKDf4SNNcjHJlLQRDEWQYxBRv5zFQhte/7SrJD2DxytAzByARD7jAiW9wSuVj8RuR4dxn/gU)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```py
f=1
for c in input():print(end=f*c.upper()or c);f=c==" "
```

Thanks to @Reticality for 3 bytes.

Comment: How about `print(end=f*c.upper()or c)`? That would save 4 bytes

Comment: @Reticality Oh wow, I had no idea you could have an empty print with just a keyword arg. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## JAVA, 273 bytes

**EDIT**

```java
import static java.lang.System.*;class x{public static void main(String[] s){char[] a=new java.util.Scanner(in).nextLine().toCharArray();boolean f=1>0;for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){if(a[i]==' '){f=1>0;continue;}if(f){a[i]=Character.toUpperCase(a[i]);f=1<0;}}out.println(a);}}
```

Comment: This is my first answer in PCG, not sure if this is acceptable.

Comment: Welcome aboard! You might try removing whitespace and using single characters for variable names. There are some other [tips for golfing JAVA](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) as well.

Comment: Thanks @nderscore for the hint, I have edited my answer using the tips.

Comment: Looking better! I also added the byte count into your post for you.

Comment: You can save a few by removing `import java.util.*;` and replacing `Scanner` with `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: You can remove the spaces in `f = 1>0;`.

Comment: Thanks guys for comment...answer updated as per your comments

Comment: The `public` keyword isn't necessary so that can save you 7 bytes.

Comment: @TuukkaX He doesn't have `public` in front of the `class`.. And if you mean he can remove the `public` in front of the `static void main(...`, then you are wrong, unless he also changes the `class` to `interface` and uses Java 8+.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yup, my mistake!

Answer (score 5):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 39 bytes

```
</?-' 'o:;?(0:<-*' '*('{'$)'`'::i
i/.0e
```

Method:

- Take one char and capitalize it if in range `a-z` then print it out. (left-to-right code for this part is `i::'backquote')$'{'(*' '*+`)
- **If** the last taken char is an EOF char **then** exit **else** print it
- **If** the last taken char is a space char **then** go to point 1 **else** take a new letter and go to point 2.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (regex solution) - 104 bytes

Someone has to bite the bullet and post the RegEx solution! 74 characters, plus the +30 character penalty:

```
alert(prompt().replace(/(^| )[a-z]/g,function(m){return m.toUpperCase()}))
```

Or if you want to read and understand the code in its non-compacted fashion:

```
//     Matches the (beginning of the line or a space), followed by a lowercase English character.  
string.replace( /(^| )[a-z]/g ,
                function(match) { return match.toUpperCase(); }
```

Comment: Clever... though of course, you've paid the price with a 30 character penalty... I take my hat off to you for biting the bullet...

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, <s>11</s>, 10 bytes

```
qqvUW@qq@q
```

Explanation:

```
qq           #Start recording in register 'q'
  vU        #Make the character under the cursor uppercase
     W       #Move forward a WORD
      @q     #recursively call macro 'q'
        q    #stop recording
         @q  #Call the recursive macro
```

Do I get a gold-badge for [outgolfing Dennis?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/the-many-memes-of-ppcg/7346#7346)

Comment: [Yes, here's your gold badge](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JmhJ1.png)

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>342</s> 310 bytes

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>-[->+>>>>+<<<<<]>[-<+>],[<[->>+>+<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<[->>+>+<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<[->-<]>>+<[>->>>+[+[<]>>+<+]>[-<<<<<<->>>>>>]<<<+++++[>+++++<-]>+>>+<<[<<<<[->+>>+<<<]>[-<+>]>>[[-]>>+<<]>>-[<<<[-<<<<->>>>]>>>+>-<]<<<<<->>>>-]>>[-<<<<[-]>>>>]<<<<<<[-]]>[->[-]<<<<<[->>>+>>+<<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]>]<<<.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFNb4MwDIb/iu9puGy7oRyGtFNP025RVAUwHyvEXQht6Z9nTqi6nuYgwhu/fmyg9LZ3zVwd11VJzSs3Sgm@8aMSSkURwyhOCWV2OucEZ0Q6VPE4z6PR5P9n7mStZIRqoTctzGbkiInNnosYWqUtlyZOwlgdXdtc4mkmbqVlgkWk1Mn0AMZRROz@1yOaN0eq21puKjL5Mnedah@f4PmdUk22M@uKBY0j@grBU3WcMqi8vS2FHXEo7IQwhblpMjiEjljBqW@RnAyENUwdOmdd31rHdR89@gUC/5GhHOytdy28vL5B6HofFhkuBJ/Uos/gq0P4mfvqCKWni4OGrvA9jycm0hk9VyAwYIGaWuYWg3XVAu/Je6F5qKGzZ4QS0UFFNICdYI9X2M88I/NbovpQLvgL)

Explanation:

```
[
* Many constants were taken from the BF constants page on esolangs.org.
*
* Cells:
*
* true number: the true index of the cell
* fake number: the relative cell index as referenced in the code
*
* true# | fake# | info
*   0       -     Used only for initialization of (fake) cell 0
*   1       -     Used only for initialization of (fake) cell 0
*   2       -     Used only for initialization of (fake) cell 0
*   3       -     Used only for initialization of (fake) cell 0
*   4       0     Holds constant 32 / ' ', which is used for cell 5 (space flag) and for subtracting (' ') from input
*   5       1     Holds the input/output char during the main loop. Also used in setup for copying cell 0 to cell 5
*   6       2     Used to hold 32 / ' ' (temporarily, to subtract it from the input)
*   7       3     Used to hold a copy of the input that gets mangled throughout the loop, being subtracted from to 
*                 check what the input character was. Also used in space code to copy cell 0 to cell 5.
*   8       4     Used primarily as a flag to decide which part of the space/not space conditional to run (if 1, the 
*                 space code runs; if 0, the not-space code runs). Also used when copying cell 3 to 6 (for checking 
*                 if cell 3 == 0), and to copy cell 1 to 3 (input).
*   9       5     Holds the 'space flag' (different from cell 4). When a space is encountered, this cell is set to 32 
*                 ('a' - 'A'). When a lowercase character is encountered, this cell is subtracted cell 1 (input), 
*                 clearing it by default (subtraction without copying implicitly clears the cell). This makes it so
*                 that only the first character after a space is converted to uppercase.
*   10      6     Used as a temporary cell when initializing constants 65 ('a' - ' ') and 2, also used in the
*                 lowercase check loop to set cell 8 (cell 3 == 0 flag)
*   11      7     Used as the counter in the lowercase check loop, goes from 26 to 0 (decrementing each iteration).
*                 Also used as a temporary cell when initializing constant 65.
*   12      8     Used to hold (cell 3 == 0) flag, which subtracts cell 5 from cell 1 if it is 1 (which means that 
*                 cell 1 is a lowercase letter).
*   13      9     Used as a flag to figure out if the else branch of the lowercase checker should run. If one, the
*                 character is not a lowercase letter or space and so cell 5 is cleared.
]

>-[-[-<]>>+<]>-    set cell 0 to 32 (=' ') 

[->+>>>>+<<<<<]    set cells 1 and 5 to 32 (end on 0)
>[-<+>]            move 1 back to 0 (end on 1) 

,[                 loop over input (cell 1) 
    
    copy cell 0 to cell 2
    <[->>+>+<<<]     [move cell 0 to cells 2 and 3 (end on 0)]
    >>>[-<<<+>>>]    [move cell 3 back to cell 0 (end on 3)] 
    
    copy cell 1 to cell 3
    <<[->>+>+<<<]    [move cell 1 to cells 3 and 4 (end on 1)]
    >>>[-<<<+>>>]    [move cell 4 back to cell 1 (end on 4)] 
    
    <<[->-<]         [subtract cell 2 from cell 3 (end on 2)] 
    
    >                cell 3 / input minus ' ' 
    
    >+<              set cell 4 as flag to run space code if set (end on 3) 
    
    [                not space branch (check if in lowercase zone)
        >-                 clear cell 4 (end on 4) 
        
        >>>+[+[<]>>+<+]>   set cell 9 to 65 (='a' minus ' ') (uses 6 7 8 as tmp) (end on 9) 
        
        [-<<<<<<->>>>>>]   [subtract cell 9 from cell 3 (end on 9)] 
        
        [need to check if cell 3 is from 0-26, it could be above and not a lowercase letter] 
        
        <<<                cell 6
        +++++[>+++++<-]>+  set cell 7 to 26
        >>+<<              set cell 9 to 1 (end on 7) 
        
        [                  do 26 times 
            
            <<<<                   cell 3
            [->+>>+<<<]            [move cell 3 to cell 4 and 6 (end on 3)]
            >[-<+>]                [move cell 4 back to cell 3 (end on 4)] 
            
            >>                     cell 6 
            
            [[-]>>+<<]             [if cell 6 is set, set cell 8 to 1 (end on 6)] 
            
            >>-                    decrement cell 8 (if cell 3 was not zero cell 8 is now zero) (if cell 3 was zero cell 8 is now 255) 
            
            [                      if cell 3 is zero (start here on 8)
                <<<                    cell 5
                [-<<<<->>>>]           [sub cell 5 from cell 1 (end on 5)] 
                
                >>>+                   clear cell 8 (end on 8)
                >-<                    set cell 9 to 0 (end on 8)
            ] 
            
            <<<<<-                 decrement cell 3 (end on 3)
            >>>>-                  end on 7 and decrement
        ] 
        
        >>[                cell 9 set (else branch so we have no lowercase letter)
            -                  [clear cell 9] 
            
            <<<<               cell 5
            [-]                [clear cell 5]
            >>>>               cell 9
        ] 
        
        <<<<<<             cell 3
        [-]                [clear cell 3]
    ] 
    
    >                cell 4
    [                space branch
        -                      clear cell 4 (end on 4)
        
        >[-]                   clear cell 5 (space flag/may have been set)
        <<<<<[->>>+>>+<<<<<]   [set space flag (cell 5) (coincidentally, it is also 32 so we can copy from cell 0) (0-> 5 and 3) (end on 0)]
        >>>[-<<<+>>>]          [3 to 0 (end on 3)] 
        
        >                      end on 4
    ] 
    
    <<<.             from 4 to 1 (output 1)
,]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 73 bytes

```python
i=raw_input()
print''.join((c,c.upper())[p==' ']for p,c in zip(' '+i,i))
```

This program capitalises a letter if preceded by a space (with a kludge for the first character in the string). It relies on the `.upper()` string method to capitalise correctly.

Comment: You could save 2 bytes by porting to Python 3.  (-4 `raw_input` => `input`, +2 `print` => `print()`)

Comment: Thanks Steven. I had considered the savings in bytes by coding in Python 3. Then I thought, if I was to change language to be competitive, I would change to Pyth. I am happy to compete in the Python 2 sub-league. I code in Python 2 every day for work, so this experience makes me better at my job (but my work code is not golfed!).

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 64 <s>76</s> <s>77</s> <s>83</s> <s>84</s> <s>89</s> bytes

Does `$_GET` count as input in PHP?
If so, here is my first CG attempt

```
foreach(explode(' ',$_GET[@s])as$k=>$v)echo$k?' ':'',ucfirst($v)
```

Thanks manatwork :)

One could just use the `ucwords` function, which would result in 21 bytes:

```
<?=ucwords($_GET[@s])
```

thanks Harry Mustoe-Playfair :)

Comment: Personally I consider only `fgets(STDIN)` to read input. But we have no consensus on `$_GET` as far as I know.

Comment: Yup, that works :D

Comment: You don't need the tricks to shut up the warnings. Thei're warnings! Nobody cares about them.

Comment: Well, didn't thought of that. Guess I'll have to stick to substr

Comment: No need for that. It's just time to forget my earlier advice on removing `$k=>`. Put it back: `foreach(split(' ',$_GET[@s])as$k=>$v)echo$k?' ':'',ucfirst($v);`

Comment: I didn't knew that you could echo multiple "things" with `,`
Thanks :)  
`split()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3 so we have to use `@` once again.
But doesn't add `split()` +30 to the bytecount? Since it splits by `regex`

Comment: Not sure. I considered that `split(' ')` equivalent of splitting on string space as used in Perl, Ruby and JavaScript answers too.

Comment: `<?= ucwords($_GET[@s])` is one byte shorter! 22

Comment: you do not even need the space between `=` and `ucwords`

Comment: I think that `$k?' ':'',` can be changed into `!$k?:' ',`, which is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: This won't work, because if `$k` evaluates to `true` it will return **1** which is then echoed

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 69

```
import Data.Char
main=interact$tail.scanl(!)' '
' '!c=toUpper c;_!c=c
```

#### Explanation:

`scanl` takes a function `(a -> b -> a)` and an initial value `a`, then iterates over a list of `[b]`s to make a list of `[a]`s:

```
scanl (!) z [a,b,c] == [   z
                       ,   z ! a
                       ,  (z ! a) ! b
                       , ((z ! a) ! b) ! c]
```

It repeatedly takes the **previous result** as the **left argument** of the function passed to it, and a **value from the input list** as the **right argument**, to make the next one.

I wrote a function `(!) :: Char -> Char -> Char` that returns the right character you pass it, but capitalizes it if the left char is `' '` (space). For `scanl`, this means: return the **value from the input list**, but capitalize it if the **previous result** was a space. So `scanl (!) ' ' "ab cd"` becomes:

```
    scanl (!) ' ' "ab cd"
==> ' ' : scanl (!) (' ' ! 'a') "b cd"
==> ' ' : scanl (!)     'A'     "b cd"
==> ' ' : 'A' : scanl (!) ('A' ! 'b') " cd"
==> ' ' : 'A' : scanl (!)     'b'     " cd"
==> ' ' : 'A' : 'b' : scanl (!) ('b' ! ' ') "cd"
==> ' ' : 'A' : 'b' : scanl (!)     ' '     "cd"
==> ' ' : 'A' : 'b' : ' ' : scanl (!) (' ' ! 'c') "d"
==> ' ' : 'A' : 'b' : ' ' : scanl (!)     'C'     "d"
==> ' ' : 'A' : 'b' : ' ' : 'C' : scanl (!) ('C' ! 'd') ""
==> ' ' : 'A' : 'b' : ' ' : 'C' : scanl (!)     'd'     ""
==> ' ' : 'A' : 'b' : ' ' : 'C' : 'd' : ""
==> " Ab Cd"
```

We need the initial value `' '` to capitalize the first letter, but then we chop it off with `tail` to get our final result.

Comment: Nice! Can you please explain it for me?

Comment: I wrote an explanation.

Comment: Some more `scanl` examples: [one](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Subfactorial+FIXED/moriA_1284954992&hs), [two](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Shifting+Pattern+Fixed/nobsun_1278360043&hs).

Comment: @Mauris kudos for using such a great algorithmm like this... :)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
uXGHr@GH1fqd@+dzTUzz
```

These multiple spaces really sucks. Otherwise there would have been a really easy 12 bytes solution.

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=uXGHr%40GH1fqd%40%2BdzTUzz&input=eCommerce%20rocks.%20crazyCamelCase%20stuff.%20_those%20%20pigeon-toed%20shennanigans.%20Fiery%20trailblazing%20345%20thirty-two%20Roger.%20The%20quick%20brown%20fox%20jumped%20over%20the%20lazy%20dogs.%20Clancy%20Brown%20would%20have%20been%20cool%20as%20Lex%20Luthor.%20good_bye&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
                      implicit: z = input string
         f       Uz   filter [0, 1, 2, ..., len(z)-1] for elements T, which satisfy:
          qd@+dzT        " " == (" " + z)[T]
                      (this finds all indices, which should be capitalized)
u                  z  reduce, start with G = z, for H in idices ^ update G by
 XGH                     replace the Hth char of G by
    r   1                upper-case of
     @GH                 G[H]
                      implicitly print result
```

edit: 16 chars is possible with @Dennis algorithm.

Comment: The multiple space thing is there to make it a lot more challenging... otherwise it would be a simple case of string.split(" ") or something similar... But you've done well to do it in 20 characters

Answer (score 3):

## PHP: <s>76</s> 74 characters

```php
foreach($l=str_split(fgets(STDIN))as$c){echo$l?ucfirst($c):$c;$l=$c==" ";}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ php -r 'foreach($l=str_split(fgets(STDIN))as$c){echo$l?ucfirst($c):$c;$l=$c==" ";}' <<< 'eCommerce rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye'
ECommerce Rocks. CrazyCamelCase Stuff. _those  Pigeon-toed Shennanigans. Fiery Trailblazing 345 Thirty-two Roger. The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs. Clancy Brown Would Have Been Cool As Lex Luthor. Good_bye
```

Comment: Instead of `ucfirst($c)`, use `$c^' '`. (Tip: if you `bitwise-xor` a letter with a space, it will be converted from uppercase to lowercase, and the oposite applies too)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, that works fine in your solution as you process only lowercase letters. But in my solution all first characters are processed. So for the (otherwise great) xor trick my code would also need some character type filtering. :(

Comment: That didn't crossed my mind. There must be a bitwise trick to check if it is a letter or not.

Comment: One thing you can do is `$l=str_split(fgets(STDIN))`, which reduces the code by 2 bytes!

Comment: Now I'm going mad. Man, how long I starred to that initialization and missed it. Thank you, @IsmaelMiguel.

Comment: You are welcome. I spent more than I should have ever spent to find something to shorten this. One thing you could do would be using `as$l=>$c`, but this way is 1 byte shorter. As an alternative to your `fgets(STDIN)`, you can use `$_GET[s]` (it throws warnings, but ignore those or add `@` before `s`). This way, it is still a standard input. And shorter. You save 4 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

## JAVA, 204 <del>211</del> <del>226</del> bytes

My first entry on CG, I hope it's fine:

```
class U{public static void main(String[]s){int i=0;char[]r=s[0].toCharArray();r[0]=Character.toUpperCase(r[0]);for(char c:r){if(c==' '&&i>0)r[i+1]=Character.toUpperCase(r[i+1]);i++;System.out.print(c);}}}
```

Saved 7 bytes thanks to @TNT

Comment: Involving my poor Java skills: `public class U{public static void main(String[]s){int i=-1,j;char[]r=s[0].toCharArray();for(char c:r)if(++i==0||c==' '&&i>0)r[j=i+(i==0?0:1)]=Character.toUpperCase(r[j]);System.out.print(r);}}`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The `public` modifier isn't necessary so you can save 7 more.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 14 bytes

It's not the shortest, but...

```
qS/Sf.{\eu}s1>
```

Another answer using similar ideas:

```
qS/Laf.{;eu}S*
```

`.x` only changes the first item if one of the parameters has only one item.

Comment: Chaining `f` and `.` is pretty ingenious. Another 14 bytes variant: `qS/Sf.{\eu}S.-`

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 61 bytes

Lua is a horrendous language to golf in, so I'm pretty proud of myself for this one.

```
print(string.gsub(" "..io.read(),"%s%l",string.upper):sub(2))
```

<s>[Try it here]</s>[1](http://goo.gl/TouhWJ) Outdated, will update tommorow

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Surely, you don't need those spaces after commas?

Comment: Wow, I'm so new to this I didnt even know spaces counted. 62 bytes!

Comment: I also just noticed it's not entirely correct: you are capitalising letters after all non-letters, so `abc_def` will give `Abc_Def`. However *only* letters after spaces should be turning into upper case. The good news is, fixing it saves a byte. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 74 bytes

```
a,b=1;main(){while((a=getchar())>0)b=isspace(putchar(b?toupper(a):a));}
```

Makes no assumptions about the run-time character set (ASCII, EBCDIC, Baudot, ...whatever).  Does assume that EOF is negative (I think C guarantees that).

```
a,b=1;
main()
{
    while((a=getchar())>0)
        b=isspace(putchar(b?toupper(a):a));
}
```

a is the input character; b is true if the last character was space.  The only non-obvious bit is that we use the fact that `putchar` returns the character printed if there's no error.

Answer (score 3):

## C# Linq - 187

This is nowhere close to winning but I just love Linq too much.

```
namespace System{using Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]a){Console.Write(a[0].Substring(1).Aggregate(a[0][0].ToString().ToUpper(),(b,c)=>b[b.Length-1]==32?b+char.ToUpper(c):b+c));}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 135 bytes

It's rare that I beat all the other answers that use the same language.

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){int c=0;for(char i:a[0].toCharArray()){System.out.print(c==0?(i+"").toUpperCase():i);c=i-32;}}}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HY9Bb4JAEIX/ysQTpIGY2l40pmlJerKX2p6MMcMywCjs0GFBV@Nvp9seX/K@L@8dccTkWJymia0jLdEQfNx6h44NjMIFtMg22jplW@32GN9CD8x6vipFI1OjAi9xN9@nTrKQXlXRR3F82/reUZvK4NIusC4y6/X8JeKH2SwO3e@uI82wpyhecrwya04Wj6v7/T5NE2XStqRhiYo59SkYxavPsKXmj4DeDWWZwsHVEhJ0XJHYxAkV0NdkLVqu0AbunUk9OEVu8gav4QEsnp7B1azOJ@4s8CkVaQpfNcHPwOYEucrZQikXOA5tF4wykgaCIAg8FFIFb9agNR7e/rtnGZoCahwJciILRqQB7GFDF9gMYWPwVyLFIff0Cw)

Comment: Suggest `var i:a[0]` instead of `char i:a[0]`

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 61

```
a="${@//: / }"
a=(${a//: / })
a="${a[@]^}"
echo "${a//:/ }"
```

Note the colons are simply to make the program display OK here.  In reality these can be some non-printable character, such as BEL.

#### Output

```
$ ./cap1st.sh "eCommerce rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye"
ECommerce Rocks. CrazyCamelCase Stuff. _those  Pigeon-toed Shennanigans. Fiery Trailblazing 345 Thirty-two Roger. The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs. Clancy Brown Would Have Been Cool As Lex Luthor. Good_bye
$
```

---

## Bash, 12

Sadly this one doesn't preserve leading/mutliple/trailing spaces, but otherwise it works:

```
echo "${@^}"
```

#### Output

```
$ ./cap1st.sh eCommerce rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye
ECommerce Rocks. CrazyCamelCase Stuff. _those Pigeon-toed Shennanigans. Fiery Trailblazing 345 Thirty-two Roger. The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs. Clancy Brown Would Have Been Cool As Lex Luthor. Good_bye
$
```

Comment: But that's half the challenge!

Comment: @Sp3000 there I fixed it (at as cost of 49 chars)

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>133</s> 131

```C#
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){var s=2>1;foreach(var c in C.ReadLine()){C.Write(s?char.ToUpper(c):c);s=c==32;}}}
```

Comment: Do you need `&&c!=32`? I'm not too fluent in C#, but I would guess that converting a space to uppercase results in a space.

Comment: Whoops, thanks - that was from before I made some other changes, I think. You're correct it's not needed.

Comment: try "using C=System.Console;" instead of using system

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 + 1 for `-s` = 16

```
{IaUC:a@0a}Ma^s
```

Explanation:

```
                  a is first cmdline arg (implicit)
            a^s   Split a on spaces
{         }M      Map this function to each element:
 Ia                 If the word is not empty,
   UC:a@0             uppercase its first character
         a          Return the word
                  Output the resulting list (implicit) joined on spaces (-s flag)
```

One interesting feature of Pip that this program draws on is the `:` assignment meta-operator. Most C-like languages have some set of compute-and-assign operators: e.g. `x*=5` does the same thing as `x=x*5`. In Pip, however, you can tack `:` onto *any* operator and turn it into a compute-and-assign operator. This even goes for unary operators. So `-:x` computes `-x` and assigns it back to `x`, the same as `x:-x` would. In this case, `UC:` is used (together with Pip's mutable strings) to uppercase the first character of a word.

The program takes input from the command-line, requiring an invocation like this:

```
python3 pip.py -se "{IaUC:a@0a}Ma^s" "test teSt TEST  _test"
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (SpiderMonkey 31 (1.8)) 63 <s>70</s>

```js
// first version
// alert([for(c of x=prompt())[x?c.toUpperCase():c,x=c<'!'][0]].join(''))
// new version, thx @nderscore
[for(c of prompt(o=x=''))o+=x=x<'!'?c.toUpperCase():c],alert(o)
```

Comment: Nice method! Here's -3 : `[for(c of x=prompt(o=''))(o+=x?c.toUpperCase():c,x=c<'!')],alert(o)`

Comment: I can't sleep... so it's -7 now : `[for(c of prompt(o=x=''))o+=x=x<'!'?c.toUpperCase():c];alert(o)`

Comment: @nderscore wow your inexhaustible. I'm sorry I never find a way to give back

Comment: I'm just happy to aid in the quest for the smallest possible JS solution :)

Comment: Array comprehensions have been dropped from ES6 and ES7 altogether. Therefore, this is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @chiru it can be invalid, but, curiously, it works. Should we call it "javascript as implemented in current release of FireFox"?

Comment: Well, it was an **experimental** SpiderMonkey feature, as it was planned for ES6 but later dropped, as no TC39 member wanted to champion it. It is [not standards-compliant](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) JavaScript and never was (and future releases of Firefox are likely drop its support).

Comment: @Chiru ok it is not standard-compliant. Who cares? It's code golf and it works.

Comment: @edc65 I'm just saying, this isn't "ES6" (which is what it says right on the top of the answer). It should rather be tagged "JavaScript SpiderMonkey 31 (1.8)", so future users are aware of why there are syntax errors when they try to run this.

Comment: @Chiru agreed. And thanx for giving the exact version.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>139</s> 105 bytes

```r
for(i in 1:length(p<-strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]])){if(i<2||p[i-1]==" ")p[i]=toupper(p[i])};cat(p,sep="")
```

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
# Assign p to be a vector of the input read from stdin, split into characters

for(i in 1:length(p <- strsplit(readline(), "")[[1]])) {

    # If we're at the first iteration or the previous character was a space

    if (i < 2 || p[i-1] == " ") {

        # Convert the current character to its uppercase equivalent

        p[i] <- toupper(p[i])
    }
}

# Join the vector elements into a single string and print it to stdout
cat(p, sep = "")
```

---

## R with regex, <s>49</s> 41 + 30 = 71 bytes

I'm really bummed; this actually has a better score using regular expressions with the penalty.

```r
gsub("(^.| +.)","\\U\\1",readline(),pe=T)
```

This matches any single character at the beginning of the string or following any number of spaces and replaces it with an uppercase version of the capture. Note that applying `\\U` is legit and has no effect for non-letters. `pe=T` is interpreted as `perl = TRUE` since it takes advantage of R's partial matching of function parameters and the synonym for `TRUE`. For whatever reason, R doesn't use Perl-style regular expression by default.

Thanks to MickyT for helping save 8 bytes on the regex approach!

Comment: With your regex the matching string could be `(^.| +.)`.  Uppercasing anything is OK.

Comment: @MickyT: Good idea, thanks! Edited to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 125

Not the shortest of solutions, but I really like to golf in C.

```
char b[99];main(c){while(scanf("%[A-Za-z_-]",b)==1)islower(*b)&&(*b&=223),printf("%s",b);~(c=getchar())&&putchar(c)&&main();}
```

ungolfed:

```
char b[99];
main(c)
{
  while(scanf("%[A-Za-z_-]", b) == 1) {
    if(islower(b[0])) {
      b[0] &= 0xDF;
    }
    printf("%s", b);
  }
  if((c = getchar()) != -1) {
      putchar(c);
      main();
  }
}
```

I don't know wheter using regex-like syntax in `scanf` is streching the rules, but it works quite nicely. (Well, technically it's not a *full* regex)

An other thing to consider is that this code only works for words shorter than 99 bytes. But I think this solution will work for most cases.

Comment: Hint: &=223 --> -=32

Answer (score 2):

**Haskell: 127 characters**

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
i=isSpace
s a b=i a==i b
u (w:ws)=(toUpper w):ws
f w=concatMap u$groupBy s w
main=interact f
```

Comment: I got down to [69 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50012/3852).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 82

```
echo join(' ',array_map(function($s){return ucfirst($s);},explode(' ',$argv[1])));
```

Usage :

```
$ php code.php "eCommerce rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <strike>201</strike> <strike>178</strike> 174 bytes

```
class C{public static void main(String[]a){for(String s:a[0].split(" ")){int c=s.length()>0?s.charAt(0):0;System.out.print((c>96&c<123?(char)(c-32)+s.substring(1):s)+" ");}}}
```

I'm back after realizing that my previous program did not preserve spaces.

First time I've had to submit an entire class before. Pass in the string as a command-line argument wrapped in quotes. (I never thought I could get it this short!)

Comment: [I did them one better :^)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185299/84303)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>64</s> <s>59</s> 63

[**Try it here**](http://repl.it/n1l/3)

This iterates through each word, converting the first character of each to uppercase, then printing it with a space after. I have to check if the split substring is not empty, which refers to multiple spaces in a row.

```python
for w in raw_input().split(" "):print w and w[0].upper()+w[1:],
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Fixed.

Comment: I think you can do `w and w[0].upper()+w[1:]`. Not sure about the input format though.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Fixed

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 66 bytes

```
Print@StringReplace[InputString[],WordBoundary~~a_:>ToUpperCase@a]
```

I would use `ToCamelCase`, but it doesn't preserve spacing.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>96</s> 93

A different approach than Alex A's.  I'm not using a loop, rather creating a another vector with a space prepended, then uppercasing any character in the original vector that is sitting under a space.

```R
p=(strsplit(readline(),''))[[1]];s=c(' ',p);p[e]=toupper(p[e<-s==' ']);cat(head(p,-1),sep='')
```

Doesn't beat the regexp version though.

**Edit** I love it when you learn something new.  Replace `p[-length(p)]` with `head(p,-1)`

Answer (score 2):

**Python 3, <strike>58</strike> <strike>63</strike> 59 chars**

```
print(*(c and c[0].upper()+c[1:] for c in input().split(" ")))
```

I have to add 5 characters because of bugfix

Comment: This not preserves multiple whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 101 bytes

```python
x=list(' '+input())
for i in range(len(x)-1):
 if x[i-1]==' ':x[i]=x[i].title()
print(''.join(x[1:]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 (non-competing)

```
$òBvU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#Hc5NbsIwFATgq8yiW7JpuQCRWLFCZY1enBfb4LxH/ZNgjtUrcLDU6nKkmU@zfbx/D8tl27jXeeZoGFHNPXUwkV61p5lDT4mRcpmmDtfstCU8vGWVXVYekRyLkHhL0nZHz7EiR/JhCPTyYvH5tUd2Pua6y6virJZjh2/H@Cne3DFEXQWTPnEr86OJunBsC0YDKka1ze0Diak4/HdXLWGEo4UxMAuMagAlnPiJU2kfm29Vx@tQ@Q8)

Not too interesting. Just a direct port of my vim answer:

```
$        #Move to the last character
 ò       #Recursively
  B      #Move back a WORD
   vU    #Capitalize
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
ṇ₁{ụʰ|}ᵐ~ṇ₁w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY49TgMxFISvMkqfLfi5ACtRpUL00bP3rW3i9QtebzYOCRI0tFyCnoYCcQNusVxksaCc0XyfRkXSNnsxZ/M8fb78PD89TF9v3@/H0/Tx@vjfjPO84Fq6jqNmRNGbvoKOdMg1dexr6hl9Gtq2wjpZKQlbZ1jCMgk36C2HQMEZCoW7dhwzUiTnlaeDCwbnF5dI1sWUl2kU3IjhWOHWMu4HpzdQUcaAVva4G7ptMcqOYyEYRZDRiCne2lPQGVd/21EG38DSjqGYA7SIB/VY8R6roXwsfiPSrFXmxS8)

```
           w    Print
                the input
ṇ₁              split on spaces
  {   }ᵐ        with every word
    ʰ           having its first letter
   ụ            uppercased
     |          (without failing on empty words)
        ~ṇ₁     and then joined by spaces.
```

If this was allowed to be a function which would normalize runs of spaces to just one space, it would only be two bytes shorter: `ṇ₁{ụʰ}ˢ~ṇ₁`. That would be another two bytes shorter if we'd figured out how to parse chained metapredicates (`ṇ₁ụʰˢ~ṇ₁`), but since handling runs of spaces requires the `|`, it doesn't actually matter for this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#εćuì}ðý
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##HY49TgMxFISvMhJ1tgEuwEpUqRB99Ox9a5t4/YJ/snEkai5DQZMy1abOlRaL6Uaa79NIIuV4XR/ul9t3WX6@lt/luq7cyzRx1Iwoep866Ejn2tPEvqfESLmMY4ddttJay8EZlrDJwgOS5RAoOEOhka@OY0WO5LzydHbB4PHpGdm6mOsmz4I3MRw7vFvGZ3F6DxVlDhjlhI8yHZpRjhwbwWiCikFM8/aegq54@d/OUvwAS0eGYg7QIh6UsOUTtqW9bH4jMuxU5T8)

**Explanation:**"

```python
#         # Split the (implicit) input-string by the space character
          # (multiple adjacent spaces will give empty items in the list)
 ε        # Map each string to:
  ć       #  Extract the head; pop and push the remainder and head separately to the stack
   u      #  Uppercase the head
    ì     #  Prepend it in front of the remainder again
     }ðý  # After the map: join by spaces (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 59 bytes

```py
print(*(w[0].upper()+w[1:]for w in input().split(' ')if w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xT8MwFIT/ym1NQESgwsJIJKZOiK2qKsd5SUwdP/Ns13X/fLCQbjnp7rvzJS7s9tvmxbjYPDT5@HzqkvckTfuYjy/vp4kFGcZV@RSbtgvemtjssGvNhNy220Y9ryuJJgjrS@igRd1Lr1ayvQqEENM0dTjXrergzUzsniLTiLCQc8qZWbna@zQkBVGUsYNVd@Nm7F/fEBcjsTzFzPjimaTD90L4TUZfMAhnh4lv@Emrr0S@ktQGoQIKRp4rt7fK6YKP/2zmZEcs6koYiBw0s4UKONANh1Q/Vv7MPJ6HQn8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 7 bytes

```
ðẆƛḣ$⇧p
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiw7DhuobGm+G4oyTih6dwIiwiIiwiZUNvbW1lcmNlIGFuZCBfZUJ1c2luZXNzIGFyZSBjb29sLCBkb24ndCB5b3UgYWdyZWUsICAgIFJpY2hhcmQgSUlJPyJd)

Fixed thanks to lyxal.

```
ðẆƛ     # Over each word...
   ḣ$ p # To the first character...
     ⇧  # Uppercase it
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve spaces, and doesn't output as a single string as required. [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiw7DhuobGm+G4oyTih6dwIiwiIiwiZUNvbW1lcmNlIGFuZCBfZUJ1c2luZXNzIGFyZSBjb29sLCBkb24ndCB5b3UgYWdyZWUsICAgIFJpY2hhcmQgSUlJPyJd) to fix it for 7 bytes.

Comment: @lyxal We probably need to fix the S flag - [this](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJTIiwiIiwi4oyIxpvhuKMk4oencCIsIiIsImVDb21tZXJjZSBhbmQgX2VCdXNpbmVzcyBhcmUgY29vbCwgZG9uJ3QgeW91IGFncmVlLCAgICBSaWNoYXJkIElJST8iXQ==) is kinda cursed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 116 bytes

Simple replacement of lowercase letters at the beginning of a word to uppercase.

This works because of how Lexurgy handles whitespace in the input. The `$` symbol denotes a word boundary, which is defined as any sort of whitespace before or after any character. As a result, input like `hello world` on a single line is considered as 2 words rather than 1 word.

```
a:
{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}=>{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}/$ _
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸®©hZÎu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=uK6paFrOdQ&input=ImVDb21tZXJjZSByb2Nrcy4gY3JhenlDYW1lbENhc2Ugc3R1ZmYuIF90aG9zZSAgcGlnZW9uLXRvZWQgc2hlbm5hbmlnYW5zLiBGaWVyeSB0cmFpbGJsYXppbmcgMzQ1IHRoaXJ0eS10d28gUm9nZXIuIFRoZSBxdWljayBicm93biBmb3gganVtcGVkIG92ZXIgdGhlIGxhenkgZG9ncy4gQ2xhbmN5IEJyb3duIHdvdWxkIGhhdmUgYmVlbiBjb29sIGFzIExleCBMdXRob3IuIGdvb2RfYnllIg)

```
¸®©hZÎu     :Implicit input of string
¸           :Split on spaces
 ®          :Map each Z
  ©         :  Logical AND with
   h        :  Replace first character with
    ZÎ      :    First character of Z
      u     :    Uppercased
            :Implicit output joined with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

### C - 85 Bytes

```
s[99]={32};j;main(i){for(;read(0,&j,1);)putchar(s[i++]=j<97|j>122|s[i-1]-32?j:j-32);}
```

Thanks to @ceilingcat because I saved 43 bytes with his modification.

**Ungolfed**

```
s[99] = {32};
j;

main(i)
{
   for( ; read(0, &j, 1); )
         
   putchar(s[i++] = j < 97 | j > 122 | s[i - 1] - 32 ?j :j - 32);
}
```

**Explanation**

A simple program that reads characters from the console and capitalizes each "valid" word and then displays it on the console as well. It was tested in GCC and it generates some warnings.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: 46 characters

```ruby
l=0
gets.chars{|c|l&&c.upcase!
l=c==" "
$><<c}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -e 'l=0;gets.chars{|c|l&&c.upcase!;l=c==" ";$><<c}' <<< 'eCommerce rocks. crazyCamelCase stuff. _those  pigeon-toed shennanigans. Fiery trailblazing 345 thirty-two Roger. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. Clancy Brown would have been cool as Lex Luthor. good_bye'
ECommerce Rocks. CrazyCamelCase Stuff. _those  Pigeon-toed Shennanigans. Fiery Trailblazing 345 Thirty-two Roger. The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs. Clancy Brown Would Have Been Cool As Lex Luthor. Good_bye
```

Answer (score 1):

## GNU sed, 20 + 1 (-r flag) +30 (regex penalty) = 51

```
s/(^| +)(.)/\1\u\2/g
```

(thks @manatwork for helping me save 4 bytes)

Usage :

```
sed 's/\(^\| \)\(.\)/\1\u\2/g' <<< "eCommerce and eBusiness are cool, don't you agree, Richard III?"
```

Comment: You have to add +30 penalty for using regular expression and +1 for the required `-r` option. By the way, no need to say [a-z] if you consume all spaces first: `s/(^| +)(.)/\1\u\2/g`

Comment: thanks -- Actually It seems (at last with GNU sed, that it dors not need the -r option)

Comment: Grr! I felt something is not optimal there since I first read this. `s/^.| +./\U&/g`

Comment: Your code has 20 bytes + 1 byte for a required r flag, so 21 without the regex penalty. It's not allowed to change the code when running it, which is what you did when adding all those escape slashes. The -r flag is given just for that purpose. Please correct the title and usage or I will downvote.

Comment: Almost there, the usage doesn't reflect the code. It should be `sed -r 's/(^| +)(.)/\1\u\2/g' <<<`.

Comment: thanks -- Actually It seems (at last with GNU sed), that it does not need the -r option

Comment: So I see usage still has a different code. I won't downvote as initially said, sorry for coming too strong at you last time.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 91+30 bytes

Well, all the ideas were used.

I had to resort to drastic measures and build a huge piece of code:

```
<?=preg_replace_callback('@( |^)([a-z])@',function($a){return$a[1].($a[2]^' ');},$_GET[s]);
```

The only function it uses is to fetch the small letters, using regex.

Comment: Your regular expression has a minor glitch. Should be `@( |^)([a-z])@` as currently not processes the first word.

Comment: @manatwork GODDAMN! I deleted the wrong char. Thanks a lot for the tip. I've fixed it now. Initially I had `@( |$|^)([a-z])@`, which didn't made sense to have the `|$` there, but deleted the very important `|^` by mistake.

Comment: Why not `ucwords`?

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Because of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49980/14732 and because of rule #1.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>143</s> <s>138</s>123 bytes

```C#
class G{static void Main(string[]a){var l=' ';foreach(var c in a[0]){System.Console.Write(l==' '?char.ToUpper(c):c);l=c;}}}
```

Runs as a command line util. Will try and golf it down from here. Comments & critique encouraged!

Comment: Instead of using `' '` you can use the ascii integer equivalent - 32 - which will save you two bytes :)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby(55)

```
gets.chars.inject(' '){|c,d|print c<?!?d.upcase():d;d}
```

I know that a better ruby solution exits in an old answer, but I like this better.

note:`c<?!` checks for chars that come before `!`, which are just control/whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol - <s>56</s> 51

```
print map-each n split input" "[uppercase/part n 1]
```

The above works correctly with the test case and also with multiple whitespace input.

An interesting (but longer!) alternative version would to use the [`parse dialect`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/parsing-summary.html) (not a regex!) which when golfed would come down to 65 chars:

```
parse s: input [any [x: thru [" " | end] (uppercase/part x 1)]] print s
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 142

First post here as well, but found that the requirements are a one to one mapping to the way Java handles arguments.

```
class X{public static void main(String[]s){for(String p:s){System.out.append(p.toUpperCase().charAt(0)).append(p,1,p.length()).append(' ');}}}
```

Unfortunately, because they are command line arguments, spaces are not preserved, and the offending words (`don't`) have to be quoted (`"don't"`). So while I didn't entirely meet all the criteria I just wanted to share a Java solution that's under 200 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy - 69

```
t=args[0];t.eachWithIndex{c,i->print!i|t[i-1]==' '?c.toUpperCase():c}
```

Answer (score 1):

## KDB(Q), 30 bytes

```
{@[x;0,1+where" "=-1_x;upper]}
```

## Explanation

```
                  -1_x            / handle case where last char is space
       1+where" "=                / find index of space and shift by 1
     0,                           / include the first char
 @[x;                 ;upper]     / apply upper case
{                            }    / lambda
```

## Test

```
q){@[x;0,1+where" "=-1_x;upper]}t
"ECommerce Rocks. CrazyCamelCase Stuff. _those  Pigeon-toed Shennanigans. Fiery Trailblazing 345 Thirty-two Roger. The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs. Clancy Brown Would Have Been Cool As Lex Luthor. Good_bye"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṣ⁶Œu1¦€j⁶
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmj4oG2xZJ1McKm4oKsauKBtg&input=&args=ZUNvbW1lcmNlIHJvY2tzLiBjcmF6eUNhbWVsQ2FzZSBzdHVmZi4gX3Rob3NlICBwaWdlb24tdG9lZCBzaGVubmFuaWdhbnMuIEZpZXJ5IHRyYWlsYmxhemluZyAzNDUgdGhpcnR5LXR3byBSb2dlci4gVGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2dzLiBDbGFuY3kgQnJvd24gd291bGQgaGF2ZSBiZWVuIGNvb2wgYXMgTGV4IEx1dGhvci4gZ29vZF9ieWU)

#### How it works

```
ṣ⁶Œu1¦€j⁶  Main link. Argument: s (string)

ṣ⁶         Split s at spaces.
      €    Each; map this over the chunks:
    1¦       Apply this to the first character:
  Œu           Uppercase.
       j⁶  Join, separating by spaces.
```

Comment: It's non-competing anyways, so you could use `K` instead of `j⁶`.

Answer (score 1):

## [s-lang](//dgrissom.com/s-lang), 8 bytes + 30 = 38

```
c![[^ ]*
```

[s-lang](//dgrissom.com/s-lang?c![[%5E%20]*)

Procedure:

- Capitalize the first letter of every range matched by the regex.

  - Any number of Every character not in Space.

Answer (score 1):

### VTL-2, 89 bytes

```
1 B=A
2 A=$
3 A=A-(32*(((B=0)+(B=32))*(A>97)*(A<123
4 $=8*(1-(A=4
5 $=B
6 #=1-(A=4
```

If I read the challenge right, input seems fairly flexible, so... This operates every time a character is input. Input is terminated by an EOT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>). Output is one character behind, so every time you input a character, the previous one will be output. This really confused my brain when I was entering the test case.

Line 1 is fairly obvious, it copies the value of `B` into `A`. It's fine to start the program from here because uninitialized variables are assumed to be 0. Line 2 takes a single character input from the terminal and assigns `A` to its ASCII value. Fairly straightforward so far. Line 3 is a bit of a doozy, but it translates to (keeping in mind that `B` is the previous character entered, and `A` is the character just entered) `IF (B==NULL OR B==" ") AND (96 < A < 123) THEN A=A-32`. Because `$` echoes, line 4 inserts a backspace character so long as `A` isn't EOT. Line 5 prints `B`, and line 6 is akin to `IF A!=EOT THEN GOTO 1`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 59 bytes

```js
n=>n.split` `.map(e=>e[0].toUpperCase()+e.slice(1)).join` `
```

As I mentioned in some of my other answers, my solutions tend to be extremely boring and unimaginative.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 57 bytes

```
readln >words [ unclip ch>upper prefix ] map ""join write
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZDNasMwEIRfZcg9vrS9tJBDDS2F0EN/TqUEWV5bm8haZSXFcV7eFT0OM/MxzGBsFl2/P9/eXx9hkmUGCxKdCwVLCU@rkul9wG4W7RN@UIL1HGHdrsRIiqg08BW/mEzEZnMUDpiVM60rtTJNpJagYk@pgVVzW1ozkW9NIqRchqHBITupCpFHkrDNQj2SoxBM4NGE2nth0gVZDfvOmxuHEXf3D8iONS/bPAs@ZCRt8OUI58L2hE5lDhjkimOZYiXKpY7N1a@ABb2Mldt6E@yC5//sLMX3cOZC6IgCrIivl2BPV@xL3Vj5o0h/6Bb6Aw)

Factor has a `capitalize` word, but for some reason it lowercases the rest of the word, so I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 33 bytes

```
irs[:'`Gf'zG!fpl**[p' -0]p' =spo]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY49a8MwGIT3/orrZAjYFNouhS41JEum0i2EVJZfS2pkvao@4sh/3hVdDg7ueThbts2EeHprvg9Tsx4eJ293u5Nv0D6da75Hz@dto57nmYIkBJbX2EEGsZZezGR7EQkx5WnqcEmaa4M3iti1iWlE1OSccEYJV7m9oVCQgjB2sGI1TuH55RVJm5BKmxbGJysKHb404TcbecUQeHGY@I6fPPtq5BuFShCqoGBkVb29FU4WfPxvF852hBY3wkDkIJktRMSR7jjm@rH6FfN4GQo9/AE)

Pretty much a straight-forward application of the rules this time...

```
irs                               - read input, reverse, stash non-zero "capitalize?" state
   [                            ] - for each codepoint in the input...
    :                             - duplicate current char
     '`G                          - is it >="a"?
        f                         - pull current char forward
         'zG!                     - is it <="z"?
             fp                   - pull current char forward, delete it
               l                  - load "capitalize?" flag
                **                - multiply all three tests values
                  [p   0]p        - if/then, true if we need to capitalize
                    ' -           - sub 32 from codepoint to capitalize
                          ' =     - is the current char a space?
                             s    - save result as "capitalize?" flag
                              p   - delete test result
                               o  - print current codepoint as a char
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 167 bytes

```
public class G{public static void main(String[]e){for(String n:e[0].split(" ")){System.out.print(n.length()<1?"":n.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+n.substring(1)+" ");}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public class G {
    public static void main(String[] e) {
        for (String n: e[0].split(" ")) {
            System.out.print(n.length() < 1 ? "" : n.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + n.substring(1) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need braces for the `For()`, and I think `substring(0,1)` can be `charAt(0)`.

Comment: The `public` modifier before the class definition can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, (ES6 RegEx Replacer) 66 bytes

```js
alert(prompt().replace(/(^[A-Z])|(\s[A-Z])/gi,m=>m.toUpperCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 35 bytes

```perl6
say slurp.split(" ")>>.tc.join(" ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY6xbsIwFEV/5YqpDHhp6cjQSJ2Yqu7oxXlxDI5f@mwTzM@nFuOR7jm6C2v43LZEFSkUXUxags9vO@z2p5PJ1lzFxxduG3cyz6yWoWJvycAqPWtHM4eOEiPlMo4GlzxJIyzescRDFh6QJo6RoncUm/ftWSuykg99oKePDu8fR@TJa66HvAp@xLEa/E6Mv@LtDb3KGjHKA9cyL60od9ZmMFqgYhDXul2gaCu@XttVShgw0Z3RM0dYkQBKOPMD59I@tr4TGS595X8)

Comment: You can rempve the `join` and just stringify it instead. `slurp` can also be `get` since there won't be newlines. [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hc6xbsMwEAPQXyEytUO8NOmYoQY6ZQq6B2f5LKmRde5JiqMM/XVX6EiAfODCGt63LVHFr@XcpSX4/LLD7vV06rLZNu5lnlkNQ8XcUgej9Kw9zRx6SoyUyzR1uGYnLWHxliXus/CI5DhGit5SbLtPz1qRlXwYAj19tHg7HJGd11z3eRVcxLJ2@HKMn@LNDYPKGjHJA99lXpood9a2YDSgYhTb3D5QNBUf/91VShjh6M4YmCOMSAAlnPmBc2kfm29FxutQ@Q8)

Answer (score 0):

## [C89 (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>60</s> 58 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
c;main(a){read(0,&c,1)&&main(putchar(a?toupper(c):c)<33);}
```

This treats non-printable ASCII as spaces (including newlines and tabs), it could be fixed for +1 byte:

```c
c;main(a){read(0,&c,1)&&main(putchar(a?toupper(c):c)==32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY9fS8NAEMS/yj6FBJqiREGtIhjwqU/ie9lsNpezl9t4f5pexa9uPPo4w8yPGarJoFXrSrsJtS2x@nGMfXmzKWhzWxXF1Z1joBFdia9B4jyzK6l6ouq5aard77pyK9PEjhic0NFvgRxeUosTmxY9gw9xGLZwCKNkBbNWLLYOwj34ka1FqxXa3HvX7BIEh9p0Bi/aKmju7iGM2oVUh0XgQxS7LXyODN9R0xE6J4uFQc7wFac5E@XELjcYMiBBLypz2/yRErxds4tE08OIJ4aO2QKJGEAPez7DPuaNma9E@kOX@I8Gg8qvtQ/9Cz08/gM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
OıḢRƤ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY-9SgNBHMRfZUh_V_gB1h5YBYRgJxL29v63u2Zv_3E_ctm8is0hkWBpp734DtrlTVzUcoaZHzOPh6iTc3xyuJ0d36fZ3fScYl9dvFx_vB7fnhaf-31oZfh3p69vangYyEuCZ7kKNaQXu9yIgWwjAiHE1Pc1llFzUVgbReyqyNQhaHJOOKOEK70rQz4jemFsa8XOOIXTs3NEbXzMVRwZC1bka9xowkMycoXW8-jQ8xb3aVgXIm_IlwahADI6VoXbWOFkxuVvduRkO2ixIbREDpLZQgTMaYt5KhsLXzF3yzbT38Uf)

##### Explanation

```python
OıḢRƤ  # Implicit input
O      # Split by spaces
 ı     # Map over this list:
  Ḣ    #  Head extract
   R   #  Uppercase
    Ƥ  #  Prepend
       # Implicit output, joined by spaces
```