# Convert the first letter of each word to uppercase, and the rest to lowercase

Tags: code-golf, string

### Description

Your task is to take a string as input, and convert the first letter of each word to uppercase, and the rest to lowercase.

### Test Cases

`Input` => `Output`

`ISN'T THIS A REALLY COOL TEST CASE???` => `Isn't This A Really Cool Test Case???`
`tHis iS A rEALLY WeiRd SeNTEncE` => `This Is A Really Weird Sentence`
`I Like This Sentence` => `I Like This Sentence`

#### Edit: no built-ins allowed.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte count wins. Good luck!

Comment: Are built-ins allowed?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, sorry. I will update that now

Comment: Since at least one current answer uses built-ins, I'd like to ever so subtly drop [this link](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1347/14215) here in the comments.

Comment: What counts as a built-in?

Comment: How do you define a *word*?

Comment: @Dennis by ops reference answer it appears to a string of chars which are space-seperated.

Comment: I'm VTC as unclear because of the severe lack of details - what counts as a built-in (surely `str.titleCase` in Python does, but where is the line?), what characters need to be supported (ASCII vs Unicode), what counts as a word (`[^ ]+` vs `\S+` in regex-speak), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize first letter of each word of input](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49950/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-of-input)

Comment: @Geobits [I disagree](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7786/8478). When there's only a few answers yet, improving the challenge is more important than avoiding the invalidation of a few answers. Of course when a rule change would require rewriting 20 answers, then it's probably not worth it, but this early on, I'm definitely n favour of the change. Nevertheless, MCMastery, I'd recommend [using the sandbox next time](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478) where details like this can be ironed out before you risk invalidating answers.

Comment: @Martin Fair enough, but I'm not convinced that this rule change did improve it, to be honest. So you rule out a couple "easy" answers, but then gain all the added complexity of defining "built-in" and defending from VTC on those grounds.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I wouldn't say it was a duplicate, as the Perl 6 answer I came up with for this one is half the length of what I came up with for that other one.

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>14</s> 8 bytes

```
gu$ògUlW
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=Z3Ukw7JnVWxX&input=SVNOJ1QgVEhJUyBBIFJFQUxMWSBDT09MIFRFU1QgQ0FTRT8_Pw)

Explanation:

```
gu$       #Make everything lowercase
   ò      #Recursively
    gUl   #Make the current character uppercase
       W  #And move forward a word
```

Here is a 9-byte, non-competing version (the old interpreter had a bug):

```
gu$Ó¼÷/Õ°
```

This version is just a regex:

```
gu$            #Make everything lowercase
   Ó¼÷/Õ°      #Expands into ':s/\<\w/\U\0/g`
```

Comment: Use a heart to mark the unprintable

Comment: I thought  this would be like vim but the `ó`s are scaring me :|

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
jdm+rhd1rtd0c
jdrR4c
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jdrR4c&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22ISN%27T+THIS+A+REALLY+COOL+TEST+CASE%3F%3F%3F%22%0A%22tHis+iS+A+rEALLY+WeiRd+SeNTEncE%22%0A%22I+Like+This+Sentence%22&debug=0)

Split into words, capitalize each, then join by space.

It is not a built-in, because `capitalize` converts `test case` into `Test case` instead of `Test Case`.

#### (with built-ins)

```
r5
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=r5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22ISN%27T+THIS+A+REALLY+COOL+TEST+CASE%3F%3F%3F%22%0A%22tHis+iS+A+rEALLY+WeiRd+SeNTEncE%22%0A%22I+Like+This+Sentence%22&debug=0)

Comment: No built-ins are allowed so make the second one your top answer

Comment: @Upgoat See, this is why you don't change rules after answers have been posted.

Comment: @Geobits idk it's just "no built-ins". It's not a radical rule change like other challenges have had

Comment: BTW, you can do 10 bytes even without `r4`. `<space>uprHqGdQd`

Answer (score 2):

## [s-lang](http://dgrissom.com/s-lang/), 7 bytes (Non-competing)

#### [Try it here!](http://dgrissom.com/s-lang/index.html?w[%20]Cc!)

```
w[ ]Cc!
```

### Explanation:

- `w[ ]` splits the input string by spaces
- `C` converts the selection (which is now the split-up words) to lower-case
- `c!` `c` converts the selection to upper-case, but since it uses the parameter `!`, it only converts the first letter of each range of characters in the selection (which are words since we split by spaces)

Comment: The regex feature of this language is cool +1

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 29 bytes

```
gets.gsub(/\S+/,&:capitalize)
```

I'm still learning ruby though >_>

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
cml5J
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=cml5J&input=SN%27T+THIS+A+REALLY+COOL+TEST+CASE%3F%3F%3F)

Split, map caps, join

Comment: Why does Pyke not default join by newlines :o

Comment: Because by default Pyke outputs the stack on multiple lines, 1 per element. It means I often don't need to join at all

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>51</s> bytes

3 bytes thanks to xnor.

```
lambda n:' '.join(a.capitalize()for a in n.split())
lambda n:' '.join(map(str.capitalize,n.split()))
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/OWLkmD)

#### using built-in, 28 bytes

```python
from string import*
capwords
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/0KuP81)

Comment: I don't think this answer is valid without actually calling anything, or taking input. (unless I missed a meta post)

Comment: It is a function, just like the ones in my challenge of binary logic gates

Comment: You can `map` the function `str.capitalize` in place of the list comp. Also, `str.title` seems to work.

Comment: @xnor `str.title` would convert `Isn't` into `Isn'T`.

Comment: I didn't suggest `map`. xnor did.

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 19 bytes

```
T`L`l
T`l`L`(^|\s).
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBMYGwKVGBsYExgKF58XHMpLg&input=SVNOJ1QgVEhJUyBBIFJFQUxMWSBDT09MIFRFU1QgQ0FTRT8_Pwp0SGlzIGlTIEEgckVBTExZIFdlaVJkIFNlTlRFbmNFCkkgTGlrZSBUaGlzIFNlbnRlbmNl)

Comment: `T01\`l\`L\`\S+`